# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable on tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I was trying to make a gui but i keep getting these errors. I looked at the questions but none have worked. I tried anything but they dont work. if you know how to fix it, please help me.

EDIT: When i extarcted onto a function intead of in the code it worked. It could be global variable thing.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from  PIL import ImageTk,Image




master = Tk()
master.title("")
master.attributes("-fullscreen", True)

width1 = master.winfo_screenwidth()
height1 = master.winfo_screenheight()
print (width1/2, height1/2)


canvas = Canvas(master, height=height1 , width=width1)
canvas.pack()



foto = Image.open("harita_50.png")
print(foto)
son = foto.resize((round((foto.width*(2/3))), round((foto.height*(2/3)))))


canvas.create_image(((width1-son.width())/2),((height1-son.height())/15),anchor=NW,image=son) 

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question!

Comment: can you add the errors

Comment: `width1-son.width()` Are you sure `son.width` is a function?  Or is it a plain attribute?

Answer (score 1):

instead of `son.width()`, try `son.size[0]` then you will get rid of `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`

Comment: i got rid of it,but there is now "line 38, in <module>
    canvas.create_image(((width1-son.size[0])/2),((height1-son.size[1])/15),anchor=NW,image=son)
  File "C:\Users\atala\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2819, in create_image
    return self._create('image', args, kw)
  File "C:\Users\atala\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2805, in _create
    return self.tk.getint(self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: image "<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGBA size=470x257 at 0x25BC741CA90>" doesn't exist" error

Comment: try printing the values by using print and check the values beforehand. If you provide full error I can help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i tried to run it on my local because there is no errors on your post

conclusion :

**use son.width and son.height without the parentheses and it will work**

calling son.width() is equivalent of 3() (if the width equals to 3)